# Pulling sequential monthly lead counts as columns in SQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

I'm trying to pull monthly lead counts for each company. I can do so for any individual month with these queries:

```
MONTH 1 LEAD COUNTS
select l.companyProfileID, count(l.id) as 'Month 1 LC'
from lead l
join companyProfile cp on cp.id = l.companyProfileID
where l.createTimestamp between cp.createTimestamp and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -1 month)
group by companyProfileID

MONTH 2 LEAD COUNTS
select l.companyProfileID, count(l.id) as 'Month 2 LC'
from lead l
join companyProfile cp on cp.id = l.companyProfileID
where l.createTimestamp between date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -1 month) and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -2 month)
group by companyProfileID
```

But instead of running 12 different queries to get a year of lead counts, I'd like to produce a single table with columns: companyProfileID, Month 1 LC, Month 2 LC, etc.

I imagine this might require an embedded select function but I'm still learning SQL on the fly. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do a single query with a `GROUP BY` to get the 12 sets of values.  Then "pivot" the data (via another query) to get the 12 columns.  Follow the tag I added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "conditional aggregates" instead of running multiple queries. In effect you move your current where conditions INSIDE an aggregate function to form a `case expression`. Note that the `count()` function ignores NULLs

```
select 
        l.companyProfileID
      , count(case when l.createTimestamp between cp.createTimestamp 
                    and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -1 month) then 1 end) as 'Month 1 LC'
      , count(case when l.createTimestamp between date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -1 month)
                    and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -2 month) then 1 end) as 'Month 2 LC'

      ... more (similar to the above)

      , count(case when l.createTimestamp between date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -11 month)
                    and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -12 month) then 1 end) as 'Month 12 LC'
from lead l
join companyProfile cp on cp.id = l.companyProfileID
where l.createTimestamp between cp.createTimestamp and date_sub(cp.createTimestamp, INTERVAL -12 month)
group by companyProfileID
```

Please also note that "between" requires the first date be earlier than the second date e.g. the following would NOT return rows:

```
select * from t where datecol between 2018-01-01 and 2017-01-01
```

this would work however:

```
select * from t where datecol between 2017-01-01 and 2018-01-01
```